# Fault free ColdFusion app update process

Tags: coldfusion

When updating a ColdFusion website, with svn or git, there is a moment where half of the repo is updated and the other half is not, during which a request could occur, which could mean epic fails in some cases.

So it seems like I need a way of pausing the requests made while svn/git is updating the folder which a website's source resides. After which point I can have a updated version number trigger the app to update itself before responding to any requests.

It's a short amount of time, but could cause many different problems depending on the app.

Does anyone have any useful advice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For our applications we follow Adam's advice and remove a node from the load balancer; however, for those who only have one server there is an easy solution.

1. Login to the ColdFusion Administrator
2. Click "Caching" on the left side bar
3. Ensure the "Trusted Cache" setting is selected.
4. Going forward, after you have completed a code checkout you will "Clear the Template Cache" which can be achieved on the "Caching" page, using the CFAdmin API or using the Adobe Air ColdFusion Server Manager application.

This setting will ensure your new CFML code is not "live" until you clear the template cache after a successful code checkout from your SCM. Additionally, this can bring a performance improvement as much as 40% since ColdFusion will no longer check your .cfc/.cfm files for changes. All production servers should run with this setting checked.

Comment: It's important to note that if there is something which triggers an onApplicationStart (or equivalent), you need to clear template cache _before_ calling this (or the old version will run). However, if your application startup generates CFML files (e.g. framework parsed files, or similar) then you *also* need to call clear template cache again _after_ these files are generated.

Comment: This is exactly how we do it on our systems.

Comment: thanks for the tip! It doesn't sound perfect though, because every cfc/cfm file isn't guaranteed to be in the cache afaict, or am I wrong?

Comment: If it's not in the cache, then it's not likely hit often enough to be in the cache, which means you're not likely to have a hit to the file while the update is happening. Nothing is foolproof :)

Comment: A single hit to the file will cache the bytecode. Your compiled files will never expire from the cache.

Comment: I suppose I could keep the cache-able files in a separate directory from the Application.cfc, then update the Application.cfc with a new version that points to another directory with a new version of the app, and then kill the cache to put this change live.

Answer (score 6):

Typically this sort of problem is mitigated when you use a cluster. (But not the primary reason to use one.) You drain all connections from one node, remove it from the cluster, update it, put it back into the cluster, remove another, and repeat, until all nodes are updated.

You don't have to do them all in serial, there are plenty of ways to do it if you have several nodes. But that's the general idea.

Answer (score 3):

If you have control of the web server, then you can re-route public requests to another folder that contains a maintenance message only. Otherwise, you can use onRequestStart to redirect all requests to a maintenance.cfm file.

Comment: but how would the maintenance file know that the git/svn update fully completed?

Comment: It wouldn't, you'd have to manually switch it back or have some build process manage it.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a thought  I don't know if it would work. But what if you were, at the beginning of your deployment process, to replace your Application.cfc with a new one that had this in the onRequestStart() method?

```
 <cffunction name="onRequestStart">
      <cfset sleep(5000) />
 </cffunction>
```

Then when the deployment is done, replace the cfc again with the original.

You might even be able to make it cleaner with a cfinclude.

```
 <cffunction name="onRequestStart">
      <cfinclude template="sleep.cfm" />
 </cffunction>
```

Then you could just replace the sleep.cfm file with an empty file when you don't want the sleep() to happen